# Total ways of creating an unconnected directed graph with $N$ nodes and $N$ edges with exactly two edges connected to each node.

Tags: graph-theory

As the title would suggest, I was wondering if there's a way to find out the total ways of creating an unconnected directed graph with $N$ nodes and $N$ edges with exactly two edges connected to each node. For example, I know that with $N = 4$, there are three ways it's possible,

$1.$ $A \rightarrow B$, $B \rightarrow A$, $C \rightarrow D$, and $D \rightarrow C$.

$2.$ $A \rightarrow C$, $C \rightarrow A$, $B \rightarrow D$, and $D \rightarrow B$.

$3.$ $A \rightarrow D$, $D \rightarrow A$, $B \rightarrow C$, and $C \rightarrow B$.

Each node is unique, so the three ways above are all considered different.

Any help would be appreciated, let me know if I need to include any more information. Thanks!

Comment: In your examples, each node is on exactly one edge.  The answer to the question you pose is also $3$, so it's hard to tell which is wrong, the question or the example.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A165652

Comment: @RobPratt I think the question actually means the vertices are labeled and the graph is "not necessarily connected"

Comment: OK, then https://oeis.org/A001205

Comment: Nice result. Grows surprisingly fast and does not seem to have a good nice formula.

Comment: Sorry, to be clearer in my example, A connected to B really means A connects to B and B connects back to A. Aka, two edges connecting to each node.

Comment: I edited my post to be clearer.

Comment: @SkylerAckerman, that means you are asking about *undirected* graphs.

Comment: In that example, the graphs I describe are undirected, yes, but take for example N=5. One possible permutation could be A->B, B->C, C->A, D->E, and E->D. Basically, making two smaller graphs with 2 nodes and 3 nodes respectively.

Comment: OK, so you want labeled directed graphs.  Now by "unconnected" did you mean disconnected or not necessarily connected?  Also, indegree = outdegree = 1 or just indegree + outdegree = 2?

Comment: Specifically disconnected. A -> B, B-> C, C -> D, D- > A would NOT be valid. And it should be indegree = outdegree = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the adjacency matrix of such a directed graph.  Each row has exactly one 1, and each column has exactly one 1, so it is a permutation matrix, of which there are $N!$.  But the connected ones correspond to $N$-cycles, of which there are $(N-1)!$.  So the desired count is $$N!-(N-1)!=N(N-1)!-(N-1)!=(N-1)(N-1)!.$$
See https://oeis.org/A001563.